# My GKeyboard keeps crashing

Tags: gboard

It crashes every time I open my phone. I'm locked out of my device and I cannot even try to factory reset it.

Answer (score 2):

it was a worldwide problem, latest update for gboard will fix it. if your device is standard configuration it will auto-update apps, in this case just enable Wi-Fi and wait for update.

if your device support usb otg connect a keyboard or mouse with usb-otg-adapter to unlock.

if you already unlocked you can speech-to-text in case you need enter text.

if you can't unlock your device, login to your google account and try to remote update gboard from pc by clicking this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin). you can also remote install any other keyboard like swiftkey.

if nothing works you can adb [sideload](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/side-loading) any official signed [apk](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/gboard) from recovery mode