# Motorola G5 GBoard Issues

Tags: locked-out, motorola, gboard

I've been having the same GBoard issues as a lot of other people , but I have been locked out of my phone because I powered it down and need to type in password to get into my phone. Any ideas as to how I should fix this issue??? I've have tried a cache partition wipe and it hasn't done anything. Thanks in advance to whoever finds a solution!

Comment: connect a keyboard or mouse with usb otg adapter

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219482