# My tablet won't let me type my password please help

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, password

I try to put my password but it's stuck there the keyboard doesn't show up so I can't put the password and I know it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My GKeyboard keeps crashing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219482/my-gkeyboard-keeps-crashing)

Comment: You can try to connect a simple USB keyboard (without integrated USB hub, [RGB] lights and so on). A lot of phones support mouse and keyboards via USP OTG.